# Can't save the ontology with NTriples (OWLAPI)

Tags: java, owl, owl-api, n-triples

I tried to save my ontology as NTriples format using owlapi.
This error appear when I try to save my ontology:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:373)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:426)
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList.get(Collections.java:1321)
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList.get(Collections.java:1321)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.model.AbstractTranslator.lambda$visit$3(AbstractTranslator.java:710)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.model.AbstractTranslator.visit(AbstractTranslator.java:709)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLSameIndividualAxiom.accept(OWLSameIndividualAxiom.java:51)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.model.AbstractTranslator.translate(AbstractTranslator.java:288)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1624)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.RDFRendererBase.createGraph(RDFRendererBase.java:484)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.RDFRendererBase.createGraph(RDFRendererBase.java:471)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.RDFRendererBase.lambda$renderEntities$5(RDFRendererBase.java:294)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:176)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1002)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.RDFRendererBase.renderEntities(RDFRendererBase.java:295)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.RDFRendererBase.renderInOntologySignatureEntities(RDFRendererBase.java:280)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.RDFRendererBase.renderOntologyComponents(RDFRendererBase.java:263)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.RDFRendererBase.render(RDFRendererBase.java:258)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioStorer.storeOntology(RioStorer.java:230)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.util.AbstractOWLStorer.store(AbstractOWLStorer.java:85)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.util.AbstractOWLStorer.storeOntology(AbstractOWLStorer.java:72)
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.saveOntology(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:1324)
    at preprocess.PositiveInference.inferringSemanticsofEquality(PositiveInference.java:117)
    at preprocess.PositiveInference.inferencing(PositiveInference.java:85)
    at preprocess.PositiveInference.main(PositiveInference.java:65)
```

And the code that referenced in error is:

```
NTriplesDocumentFormat nTriplesFormat = new NTriplesDocumentFormat();

try {
        ontologyManager.saveOntology(ontologyInferred, nTriplesFormat, IRI.create(file.toURI()));
} catch (OWLOntologyStorageException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The ontology:

```
SameIndividual(<http://www.example.com/individual/eq#PB> )
SameIndividual(<http://www.example.com/individual/eq#transY> )
SameIndividual(<http://www.example.com/individual/eq#symX> )
SameIndividual(<http://www.example.com/individual/eq#OC> )
SameIndividual(<http://www.example.com/individual/eq#transZ> )
SameIndividual(<http://www.example.com/individual/eq#SAA> )
SameIndividual(<http://www.example.com/individual/eq#transX> )
SameIndividual(<http://www.example.com/individual/eq#OAC> )
SameIndividual(<http://www.example.com/individual/eq#refO> )
SameIndividual(<http://www.example.com/individual/eq#refS> )
SameIndividual(<http://www.example.com/individual/eq#SA> )
SameIndividual(<http://www.example.com/individual/eq#PAB> )
SameIndividual(<http://www.example.com/individual/eq#transX> <http://www.example.com/individual/eq#transY> <http://www.example.com/individual/eq#transZ> )
SameIndividual(<http://www.example.com/individual/eq#symY> )
```

The reflexsive sameAs axiom result of inferrencing based on OWL 2 RL/RDF rules eq-ref

If: T(?s, ?p, ?o) then: T(?s, owl:sameAs, ?s)

> SameIndividual(http://www.example.com/individual/eq#PB )

The inferencing code:

```
result.add(dataFactory.getOWLSameIndividualAxiom(individual, individual));
```

I can save my ontology as OWLXMLFormat, but since I am building a dataset that need in triple form. Is there any solution to save it in any triple form?

Other Format already tried and error:

```
NTriplesDocumentFormat nTriplesFormat = new NTriplesDocumentFormat();
N3DocumentFormat n3Format = new N3DocumentFormat();
TrigDocumentFormat trigFormat = new TrigDocumentFormat();
TurtleDocumentFormat  turtleFormat = new TurtleDocumentFormat();
RioTurtleDocumentFormat  rioFormat = new RioTurtleDocumentFormat();
```

**Edit:**

The full inferrence code:

```
public class InferredSameIndividualAxiomGenerator extends InferredIndividualAxiomGenerator<OWLSameIndividualAxiom>{
    
    @Override
    protected void addAxioms(OWLNamedIndividual entity, OWLReasoner reasoner, OWLDataFactory dataFactory, Set<OWLSameIndividualAxiom> result) {

        Set<OWLNamedIndividual> sameIndividuals = asUnorderedSet(reasoner.getSameIndividuals(entity).entities());
        sameIndividuals.add(entity);
        result.add(dataFactory.getOWLSameIndividualAxiom(entity, entity));
        if (sameIndividuals.size() > 1) 
            result.add(dataFactory.getOWLSameIndividualAxiom(sameIndividuals));
    }

    @Override
    public String getLabel() {
        return "Same Individuals T(?x, owl:sameAs, ?y)";
    }
}
```

Comment: that should be a bug. You should open a Github issue. OWL API does use sets for keeping the individuals of the sameAs axiom, but indeed the N-Triples representation does need 2 individuals, thus, the exception occurs as there is only one individual in the set. A simple check for size = 1 in particualr axioms should solve this issue. But you have to report it, or even provide a fix and do a pull request

Comment: `result.add(dataFactory.getOWLSameIndividualAxiom(entity, entity));` I'm not sure what's the purpose of this line. The axiom being created is not inferred by the reasoner, and is not a valid OWL 2 axiom. Removing this line might fix your problem.

Comment: @Ignazio tried to create inferrence for OWL 2 RL Rule Semantics of Equality, and that line purpose is for Rule eq-ref, that If: T(?s, ?p, ?o), then: T(?s, owl:sameAs, ?s), T(?p, owl:sameAs, ?p), T(?o, owl:sameAs, ?o). If I deleted the line, is there any alternative way I can produce the inference?

Comment: No good ways with OWLAPI, not at the moment :-( the problem is that the inferences you wish to write out can be expressed as RDF triples but not at all as OWL axioms, so OWLAPI and RIO (the formats you have tried span both OWLAPI and RIO formats) doesn't expect that. There's an open request to allow such constructs to work via some mechanism, so that applications can choose to work with non-OWL-compliant axioms, but it's not implemented yet. What I'd do with the current stack is write out the NTRIPLE content without those triples and then add them manually to the file, which isn't that great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround [ONT-API](https://github.com/owlcs/ont-api) could be used.
Since ONTAPI is a RDF-centric OWLAPI implementation, there must be no problem with any RDF-serialization (by default there is a substitution of OWLAPI formats with Jena alternatives).
But, axiom `SameIndividual(x, x)` is still illegal, and to create such construction need to switch to RDF API.

Example:

```
    OWLOntologyManager m = OntManagers.createManager();

    OWLOntology ont = m.createOntology();
    String i = "http://i";

    OntModel g = ((Ontology) ont).asGraphModel();
    g.createIndividual(i).addSameIndividual(g.createIndividual(i));

    ont.saveOntology(new NTriplesDocumentFormat(), System.out);
```

Output:

```
<http://i> <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs> <http://i> .
<http://i> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#NamedIndividual> .
_:B0ee0d3dfX2D1fe4X2D4489X2D9fc3X2De18bae6cfab4 <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Ontology> .
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception is a bug (please report it, as recommended in the comment), however note that those are not legal OWL axioms. The syntax and semantic specification shows sameAs as requiring two arguments at least.

(Consider that the axiom is supposed to allow definition of synonym individuals; one argument only offers no new information)

If the axioms are generated by an inferred axiom generator, looks like that code has a bug as well.